# How and why did Magneto rejoin the X-Men?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, x-men-the-last-stand, x-men-first-class, x-men

At the end of the movie *X-Men: First Class*, Magneto leaves Charles Xavier and the X-Men to go start the Brotherhood of Mutants.  Between the end of *X-Men: First Class* and the beginning of *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, Magneto is imprisoned because he is falsely accused of assassinating John F. Kennedy.  Chronologically, the next time we see Magneto in the original timeline is the flashback scene shown in the beginning of the movie *X-Men: The Last Stand*, where in the 1980’s Magneto helps Charles Xavier recruit Jean Gray as a girl into the X-Men.

My question is, how did Magneto go from Charles’ adversary in the 1970’s to being part of the X-Men again in the 1980’s?  And how did he go from being part of the X-Men in the 1980’s back to being Charles’ adversary at the time of the original *X-Men* movie?

Is this just a continuity error, or is there some in-Universe explanation for this?  Do DVD commentaries, interviews, etc. shed any light on what happened in the original timeline between the 1970’s and the 1980’s, and between the 1980’s and the time of *X-Men*?

Comment: It happened in the comics multiple times, when the goals of both parties coincided. I don't think this was ever properly explained in the films.

Comment: I note from Magneto's origin story that he was not a committed villain. On the other hand, he was, in a very definite sense, a racist -- pro-mutant and anti-human. Perhaps, being an intelligent man, he eventually came around philosophically and saw the error in such an extreme position.

Comment: @releseabe I mean, if he saw the error in his position between the 1960’s and the 1980’s, then he apparently fell into error again sometime between the 1980’s and the 2000’s (or whenever the “not too distant future” of the original X-Men movie takes place).

Comment: yes. ultimately it is a comic book.

Comment: My memory is pretty fuzzy but in the comics I think secret wars is the event which allies Magneto with the X men after he has to do some soul searching because he almost kills Kitty Pride and she is a Jew and after surviving Auschwitz his entire philosophy is based on his experience of seeing humankind at it's worst in the attempt by Hitler to exterminate the Jews. so then some other things happen and then in secret wars Beyonder kidnaps some heroes and villains and Magneto joins the X men in the rescue attempt. or something. AFAIK there is no proper explanation in the movies.

Comment: Actually after a quick google search "Magneto finds himself allied with Professor Xavier and the X-Men when a group of heroes and villains are abducted by the Beyonder, a nearly omnipotent alien being. This entity took them to a planet he created called the Battleworld to participate in a personal experiment of his to observe the concept of the battle between good and evil which would later be known as the Secret Wars." And you can read more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto_(Marvel_Comics) under the subheading of "reformation" which you may or may not choose to read more of.

Comment: Incidentally, racism is the belief that another race or ethnicity is inferior, Magneto displays speciesism, the belief that you are superior to another species as his belief is that mutants are a superior species to humans via evolutionary progress. Race does not play a part in his belief. See this link for info on speciesism https://www.livekindly.com/speciesism-animal-rights-issue/

Comment: I mean this explanation wouldn’t fit in the movie, since Kittie Pride wasn’t even born between the time of X-Men: Days of Future Past and X-Men: Apocalypse.